# Some interesting integrals with dilogarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

Calculating without techniques involving the contour integration

$$a) \ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^2-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^2}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x;$$

$$b) \ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^3-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^3}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x.$$

I'm working now on such a method. What would your *real method* inspiration be here?

*Supplementary question*: Calculate

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^4-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^4}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x.$$

Moreover, may we hope for a generalization of the type below?

$$ I(n)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^n-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^n}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x.$$

**Preparing another two generalizations:**
$$ i) \ J(n,m)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_m(e^{-i x}))^n-(\operatorname{Li}_m(e^{i x}))^n}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x;$$

$$ ii) \ K(n)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{-i x})\cdots \operatorname{Li}_n(e^{-i x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{i x})\cdots \operatorname{Li}_n(e^{i x})}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Consider the Integral 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\frac{\text{Li}^2_2(e^{i x})-\text{Li}^2_2(e^{-i x})}{2 i \sin(x)}
$$
using the series representation for the dilogarithm this can be rewritten as

$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\sum_{n,m>0}\frac{1}{n^2 m^2}\frac{\sin(m+n)x}{\sin(x)}
$$
exchange summation and integration, using the simple fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}dx \frac{\sin(lx)}{\sin(x)}=2 \pi \delta_{l,0}$ for $l \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ we get

$$
I=2  \pi s^{(2)}_2 =2 \pi\sum_{\substack{n,m>0 \\n+m=odd}}\frac{1}{n^2 m^2}
$$

Comment: The closed form solution to $s^{(2)}_2$ is pretty simple to obtain. Observe to fullfil the condition $n+m=odd$ either $n$ has to be odd and $m$ to be even, or vice versa. This means we have $2$ possible combinations of even and odd which yield a contribution to our sum.

$$
 s^{(2)}_2 =2\sum_{\substack{n>0,m\geq 0}}\frac{1}{(2n)^2 (2m+1)^2}=2\frac{\zeta(2)}{4}\frac{3\zeta(2)}{4}=\frac{3}{8}\zeta^2(2)
$$

Comment: this strategy can indeed generalized to yield most of the results in your question

Comment: @tired Yeap, nicely done over there.

Comment: @tired maybe you later consider turning your ideas into an answer that also covers the generalizations.

Comment: okay $J(3,3)=\pi\frac{91}{64}\zeta^3(3)$ also works out nicely...lets see what i can do tomorrow

Comment: this seems to deviate from your closed form, but fits numerically

Comment: @tired my formula gives the same value.

Comment: here we go.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Getting an idea by going trough an example**

Consider the Integral 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\frac{\text{Li}^2_2(e^{i x})-\text{Li}^2_2(e^{-i x})}{2 i \sin(x)}
$$
using the series representation for the dilogarithm this can be rewritten as

$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\sum_{n,m>0}\frac{1}{n^2 m^2}\frac{\sin(m+n)x}{\sin(x)}
$$
exchange summation and integration and using the simple fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}dx \frac{\sin(lx)}{\sin(x)}=2 \pi$ for $l \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ we get

$$
I=2  \pi s^{(2)}_2 =2 \pi\sum_{\substack{n,m>0 \\n+m=odd}}\frac{1}{n^2 m^2}
$$

The closed form solution to $s^{(2)}_2$ is pretty simple to obtain. Observe to fullfil the condition $n+m=odd$ either $n$ has to be odd and $m$ to be even, or vice versa. This means we have $2$ possible combinations of even and odd which yield a contribution to our sum.

$$
 s^{(2)}_2 =2\sum_{\substack{n>0,m\geq 0}}\frac{1}{(2n)^2 (2m+1)^2}=2\frac{\zeta(2)}{4}\frac{3\zeta(2)}{4}=\frac{3}{8}\zeta^2(2)
$$

the strategy for providing a closed form solution will follow the same arguments, except that we additonally need a combinatoric lemma proven in the appendix

**The General Case**

We now want to investigate

$$
I^{(r)}_n=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\frac{\text{Li}^n_r(e^{i x})-\text{Li}^n_r(e^{-i x})}{2 i \sin(x)}
$$

Going through the same procedure then in the motivating example we might show that

> $$
> I^{(r)}_n=2 \pi s^{(r)}_n
> $$

This means we are interested in a family of Euler like sums, since

$$
s^{(r)}_n=\sum_{\substack{ k_i \geq 1, \\ \sum_{n\geq i \geq 1} k=odd }}\frac{1}{\prod_{ n \geq i\geq1}{k^r_i}}
$$

we now have to take care that we account for all possible partitions of the integers such that the constraint $\sum_{n\geq i \geq 1} k=odd$  is fulfilled. As shown in the Appendix, we have to choose $2l-1$numbers to be odd and $n-2l+1$ to be even. Each of this partitions contains $N_{l,n}=\binom{n}{2l-1}$ equivalent combinations.
This means that

$$
s^{(r)}_n=\sum_{l_{max}(n)\geq l\geq1}N_{l,n}\sum_{k_i\geq 1, K_i \geq 0}
\prod_{2l-1 \geq i\geq1}\frac{1}{{(2K_i+1)^r}}
\prod_{n- 2l+1 \geq i\geq1}\frac{1}{{(2k_i)^r}}
$$

using now the well known identity $\sum_{k\geq 0}(2m+1)^{-r}=(1-1/2^{-r})\zeta(r)$ we can carry out the infinite summations
$$
s^{(r)}_n=\sum_{l_{max}(n)\geq l\geq1}\frac{N_{l,n}}{2^{r(n-2l+1)}}(1-\frac{1}{2^{r}})^{2l-1}\zeta^n(r)=\sum_{l_{max}(n)\geq l\geq1}c_{l,n}\zeta(r)^n
$$

Furthermore the sum over coefficents can be done in closed form by virtue of the Binomial identiy:

> > $$
> > s^{(r)}_n=C_{n,r}\zeta(r)^n\,\,,\,\,C_{n,r}=\begin{cases}
> > \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{2^{n-r}}{4^{r n/2}}(2^{r-1}-1)^n\right)\,\, \text{if} \,\,n \,\, even\\
> > \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{2^{n-r}}{4^{r(n-1)/2}}(2^{r-1}-1)^n\right)\,\, \text{if} \,\,n \,\, odd \\
> > \end{cases} 
> > $$

Note that we get the sums with the constraint $\sum_{n\geq  i\geq1} k_i=even$ for free: 
$$
\bar{s}_n^{r}=\left(1-C_{n,r}\right)\zeta(r)^n
$$

It is also interesting to note, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{s^{(r)}_n}{\zeta(r)^n}=\frac{1}{2}$
which can be traced back to fact that for very large $n$ we have to choose roughly $n/2$ odd factors out ouf $\sum_{n\geq 1 i\geq1} k_i$ due to concentration of $N_{l,n}$ around $n/2$.

Last but not least a few examples:

\begin{align*}
 s^{(2)}_2=\frac{3}{8}\zeta^2(2)\,\, ,\,\,\bar{s}^{(2)}_2=\frac{5}{8}\zeta^2(2) \\
s^{(3)}_3=\frac{91}{128}\zeta^3(3)\,\, ,\,\,s^{(3)}_5=\frac{1267}{2048}\zeta^5(3), 
\end{align*}

**Appendix: A small detour to combinatorics**

Consider the sum of integers

$$
c_m=n_1+n_2+...+n_m
$$
how can we partion $c_m$ into odd and even elements, such that $c_m$ is odd?
Since the odd and even numbers furnish a representation of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ it follows trivially 
that we need always an odd number $2l-1$ of the $n_m$'s to be odd. For any fixed $l$ we then have

$$
N_{l,m}=\binom{m}{2l-1}\,\, ,\,\, l \in
\begin{cases}
\{1,m/2\} \,\, \text{if} \,\,m \,\, \text{even}\\
\{1,\lceil m/2 \rceil\} \,\, \text{if} \,\,m \,\, \text{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
equivalent admissible partitions of $c_m$.

Answer (score 9):

$ \large \text{ Hooray!!!}$ The closed-form of the integral $a)$ is impressive. According to my calculations,

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^2-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^2}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^5}{48}.$$

**Including also the trivial case, $n=1$,**

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x})}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}{4}.$$

$ \large \text{ Second Hooray!!!}$

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^3-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^3}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^7}{192}.$$

$ \large \text{Third Hooray!!!}$

**I think I have found a first generalization!**

$$ I(n)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x}))^n-(\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x}))^n}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{6^n}\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right).$$

$ \large \text{Fourth Hooray!!!}$

**Guess what?!** I'm also done with the generalization $J(n,m)$
$$\ J(n,m)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\operatorname{Li}_m(e^{-i x}))^n-(\operatorname{Li}_m(e^{i x}))^n}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\pi(\zeta(m)^n-((2^{1-m}-1)\zeta(m))^n).$$

$ \large \text{Fifth Hooray!!!}$

I computed $2$ cases of the generalization in $K(n)$ and I approach the solution of the generalization. So, 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{-i x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{i x})}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{5}{48}\pi^3\zeta(3);$$
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{-i x})\operatorname{Li}_4(e^{-i x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{i x})\operatorname{Li}_4(e^{i x})}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{17}{6912}\pi^7 \zeta(3).$$

$ \large \text{Sixth Hooray!!!}$

Looks like I have been lucky today! Let me put the last generalization I just proved in a nice form

$$K(n)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{-i x})\cdots \operatorname{Li}_n(e^{-i x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i x})\operatorname{Li}_3(e^{i x})\cdots \operatorname{Li}_n(e^{i x})}{e^{-i x}-e^{i x}}\textrm{d}x$$

$$=\pi \left(\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\cdots \zeta(n)+(-1)^{n-1} \eta(2)\eta(3)\cdots\eta(n))\right).$$

**Extra information**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: Or those mere mortals lack the audacity to vote! :P$$\phantom{}$$Also, can you include how you derived the identity for (a)? I’m very much interested

Comment: @FrankW. do your best first.

Comment: your "trivial" case can be deduced from the series representation of dilog together with the fact that over a period the integral of $\sin(mx)/\sin(x)$ always equals $2 \pi $ if $m$ is odd $0$ otherwise. guess the other equalities can be deduced through similar arguments, maybe with a bit of more work for the final sum...

Comment: ps: i guess you would get more upvotes if you share more of your efforts...nevertheless +1 form me for the interesting question

Comment: @Waiting Okay I've managed to transform the integral into$$I=2\int\limits_0^{2\pi}dx\,\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac {\sin nx}{n^2\sin x}\sum\limits_{m\geq1}\frac {\cos mx}{m^2}$$Can you give me a hint as to what to do next?

Comment: @FrankW. For the way you chose, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: @tired For me points on MSE mean nothing, but for such a question at least would be a sign of the community's interest in out of order questions. Having a high reputation doesn't mean you are an artist in mathematics. They are interesting with or without adding more information.

Comment: for $n=4$ is $\frac{5 \pi ^9}{6912}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk my formula confirms the value you found is perfect.

Comment: @Waiting, i don't care about reputation neither (there are way more important things in my life then MSE) and i can follow your argument (that a question can be interesting for itself, without any further effort by an OP) but we have to keep in mind that this is not the intended scope of this website....

Comment: @FrankW. please see my answer---